# Validating Regular Sentence Grammar with Regex

Tags: php, regex, grammar

So I want to validate a string based on whether or not it contains only grammatical characters as well as numbers and letters.(basically A-Z, a-z, 0-9, plus periods(.), commas(,) colons(:), semicolons(;), hyphens(-), single quotes('), double quotes(") and parentheses().  I am getting a PHP error that says "Compilation failed: range out of order in character clas".  What regex code should I be using?

This is the one I'm currently using:
`^[a-zA-Z0-9_:;-()'\" ]*^`

Comment: What do you mean by "grammatical characters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `-` which would then become this `^[a-zA-Z0-9_:;\-()'\" ]*` . `-` has a special meaning inside character set so it needs to be escaped. `^` in the end is also not necessary. The regex can also simplified using `\w` like this

```
^[\w:;()'"\s-]*
```

`\w` matches letters, digits, and underscores.

Comment: Ahh, did not realize I had to escape hyphens.  Thank you.  Your answer will be accepted once it allows me to accept it.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 It is better if you use `\s` in place of ` ` because it might be more clear that a space is involved. Also, it is not necessary to escape `"`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a dash character in the regex, which the parser is interpreting as a range instead of as a literal dash. You can fix that by:

- Escaping it with a backslash (`^[a-zA-Z0-9_:;\-()'\" ]*^`)
- Putting it at the start (`^[-a-zA-Z0-9_:;()'\" ]*^`)
- Putting it at the end (`^[a-zA-Z0-9_:;()'\" -]*^`)